# Random number for Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: c, random

just a quick question. 
I'm very new to c++. here I've created a random number generator which should get a random number from 1-3 and then each number corresponds to rock paper or scissors.

The problem is, it picks scissors (3) every time!! What have I done wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int i, a, b;
int playerschoice, compchoice;

main()
{
    compchoice=rand() %3+1;
    printf("compchoice=%d",compchoice);

    if (compchoice == 1)
    {
        printf("\nThe computer is going with: Rock...\n");
        b = 0;
    }
    else if (compchoice == 2)
    {
        printf("\nThe computer is going with: Paper...\n");
        b = 1;
    }
    else if (compchoice == 3)
    {
        printf("\nThe computer is going with: Scissors...\n");
        b = 2;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged as C++, but it looks an awful lot like C.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer below, could you accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to seed the random number generator with a value that would be different each time you run it.

Do the following before calling `rand()`

```
/* initialize random seed: */
  srand (time(NULL));
```

**EDIT - Added more information**

The rand() function is a [pseudo-random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). What that basically means is that given an initial starting condition the function will produce a sequence of numbers that *appear* to be random.

What srand will do is set that initial starting condition for you. time(NULL) just returns the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.

Have a look at this article for more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EywTURfi/

Comment: Thank you so much, I would never have known to do that! So what does that actually do?

Comment: I've edited the original answer with more information.

Answer (score 1):

The seed for the random number generator is always the same upon program start.
Therefore the chosen random number is always the same.

Add this line at the beginning of your program to initialize the random number generator using the current time as seed:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

put `srand(time(NULL));` before `compchoice=rand() %3+1;` so it will work properly and it will generate random numbers every times when you run any program.